# Plotting intersection of a sphere with a plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I've made the following code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[ball color=red] (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\fill[opacity=0.5,blue] (-3,0,1) -- (-1,2,1) -- (5,2,1) -- (3,0,1) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Which I've adapted from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61880/3d-image-using-tikz) (thank you very much!). And which produces:

[image]

But I want to do is this:

[image]

> **Question:** How could I do the *intersection* of the sphere with the plane?

Comment: Does it need to be "true" 3D? Or is it sufficient to look like it? The former is more difficult (especially with TikZ), the latter is way less flexible.

Comment: It doesn't need to be true 3D. I just want it to look like if it was. ;)

Comment: Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169681/draw-parallels-of-a-sphere-with-tikz/169685#169685

Comment: it helps if the ellipse has the same aspect ration (width to height) at the parallelogram.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution with Asymptote:

[image: plane and sphere]

The code to produce it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=SphereAndPlane}
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 8;
size(10cm, 0);  // Final image will be 10cm wide, unlimited height.
import three;   // Enable three-dimensional functionality.
currentprojection = orthographic(2,5,1);

draw(unitsphere, red);
draw(surface((-2,-2,0) -- (-2,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,-2,0) -- cycle), blue + opacity(0.5));

\end{asypicture}

\end{document}

% file: foo.tex
% to compile: pdflatex --shell-escape foo
%
% For MikTeX users: Asymptote requires a separate program that cannot be installed
% by the package manager. You can get the installation file from
% https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.35/
% (specifically, the file ending in setup.exe).
```

If you are using a relatively recent version of MacTeX (or, I assume, TeX Live), with a full installation, this should just work. If you are using MikTeX, you will need to install [the Asymptote program](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.35/) as described in the comments after `\end{document}`.

Comment: Nice! Sorry I forgot to mention Asymptote. Probably one day I'll have a look at it.

Comment: +1 for `asypictureB`

Answer (score 11):

Here you have an idea for both: the "fake" 3D draws two planes, one "behind" the ball, and one "in front of". The 3D effect is achieved by cutting out a half ellipse. The "less fake" 3D approach uses *pgfplots* to first draw the lower hemisphere, then the surface, and then the upper hemisphere. Probably someone will upload a *pstricks* solution, as it is vastly superior at 3D stuff.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue!50!gray, opacity=0.7] (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (4,2) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
    \shade[ball color=red] (2.5,0) circle (1);
    \fill[blue!50!gray, opacity=0.7] (0,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.5) -- (5,0) -- (6,-2) -- (-1,-2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [   axis equal,
        hide axis,
        view={30}{30},
        z buffer=sort,
    ]
        \addplot3
        [   domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:180,
            surf,
            shader=flat,
            red,
            opacity=0.5
        ] ({sin(y)*cos(x)},{sin(y)*sin(x)},{cos(y)});
        \addplot3
        [   domain=-2:2,
            y domain=-2:2,
            surf,
            shader=flat,
            blue,
            opacity=0.5,
        ] (x,y,0);
        \addplot3
        [   domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:90,
            surf,
            shader=flat,
            red,
            opacity=0.5,
        ] ({sin(y)*cos(x)},{sin(y)*sin(x)},{cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=50 0 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=70,lightsrc=80 20 70,
       linewidth=0.001pt,action=none}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-2)(4,2)
%\axesIIID(3,3,6)
\psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,args={[0 0 1 0]},
base=-3 3 -2 2,ngrid=20 20,fillcolor=red!30,name=B1]
\psSolid[object=sphere,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=18 36,
name=C1,action=none]
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=B1_s C1,action=draw**]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew I could count on you to provide a _pstricks_ solution :-)